# How to change navigation panel text Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

Is there a way how to change navigation bar title to something else using c# code?

[image]

Comment: Is this Xamarin Android or Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reply, but your answer might be correct, but it is too complicated for beginners.

So i found easy solution: `titleName.Title = "myTitle";`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="BlankApp.Procv"
         x:Name = "titleName"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app is a xamarin android app, then in activity, you can use `SetTitle` function to achieve this.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity 
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            SetTitle(Resource.String.test);
        }
     }
```

Note: `test` is a string defined in `string.xml`

If your app is a xamarin.form app, you can do as follows:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Title = "Test title";
    }
}
```